# How can a method of an object refer to an inner class of that object?

Tags: scala, object, methods, inner-classes

I was scrolling through [Scalameta's code named Trees.scala](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/main/scalameta/trees/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/Trees.scala) and I stumbled upon this piece of code that I have had a hard time understanding.

```scala
@branch trait Name extends Ref { def value: String }
object Name {
  def apply(value: String): Name = if (value == "") Name.Anonymous() else Name.Indeterminate(value)
  def unapply(name: Name): Option[String] = Some(name.value)
  @ast class Anonymous() extends Name {
    def value = ""
    checkParent(ParentChecks.NameAnonymous)
  }
  @ast class Indeterminate(value: Predef.String @nonEmpty) extends Name
}
```

Here, Metals points out that

```
value Indeterminate is not a member of scala.Meta.Name
value Anonymous is not a member of scala.Meta.Name
```

So, it is complaining that `apply` cannot refer to the inner classes. Despite the above, the source actually succeeds to compile. However, the code below does not, which the above code essentially boils down to:

```scala
trait Hihi {   }
object Hihi {
  def apply(value: String): Hihi = if (value == "") Hihi.Class1() else Hihi.Class2()
  @ast class Class1() extends Hihi {
    def value = ""
  }
  @ast class Class2() extends Hihi
}
```

The `scalac` compiler points out that `Class1` and `Class2` is not a member of `Hihi`. Then, why does Scalameta's code compile while the other, the simpler one, fails?

Comment: Do you have the same macros loaded in?

Comment: @sinanspd Oops, good point. I have not yet checked that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, sans the annotations (in Scala 2, thus why `Bar` and `Baz` are `case class`es):

```
trait Foo { }

object Foo {
  def apply(v: String): Foo = if (v.isEmpty) Foo.Bar() else Foo.Baz(v)

  case class Bar() extends Foo { def value = "" }
  case class Baz(value: String) extends Foo
}
```

I suspect that if you don't have the `ast` annotations in scope, `@ast class Class1` fails to compile which renders `Class1` not a member.